# Postgres SQL Conversion Date

Tags: sql, postgresql, talend, postgresql-9.3

I'm using Talend to extract data from excel to my database postgres, but when i integrate them to my database he convert the column `Date` to the original date of his system now I want to convert this date to my normal date, I guess its the internal format for storing dates in postgres, you can find an explication below :

Excel file :

```
    Date       |     price

  15/08/2018   |    100 usd
  15/09/2018   |    150 usd
  15/10/2018   |    058 usd
```

Postgres database :

```
       Datex   |   pricex

       43327   |    100 usd
       43358   |    150 usd
       43388   |    058 usd
```

Comment: I dont understand how it is like 15/02/2018 = 32458, what is the pattern?

Comment: That's a weird format. What's the type of the _date_ column?

Comment: im using Talend to extract data from excel to my database postgres but when integrate them to the database he convert the colomun Date to the original date of his system now i want to convert this date to my normal date  @ErayBalkanli

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do:

```
select '2018-02-15'::date + (date - 32458) * interval '1 day'
```

That is, just do the arithmetic, if you know what one of the date values should be.